# TKinter - File Upload Button, Change Color of Button

Tags: python, tkinter, button, customtkinter

I have this code for TKinter and CustomTkinter to create a file upload button:

```
def import_file_data():
    v = tk.StringVar()
    global file_data
    csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
    v.set(csv_file_path)
    file_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path) 

file_button = ctk.CTkButton(root, text = "File Upload", command=import_file_data)
file_button.grid(row=5,column=0, padx=buttonx, pady=buttony)
```

This button is blue with white text by default and I want to make it so it turns green on the click action of the button to signify that a file was successfully uploaded.

I know Tkinter offers a `.after` function which might help. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder because I am new to Tkinter and couldn't find it online with what exactly I wanted. Not every one is advanced like you.

Answer (score 0):

you can change to color after clicking by setting a timer in millisecodns in my case i have set it to 2000milliseconds i.e. 2seconds you can set it to 0:
Here is a code for better understanding:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry("550x400")
def import_file_data():
    print("Importing file data...")

def schedule_import():
    file_button.after(2000, import_file_data) # time in 2000ms you can set it to 0

file_button = ctk.CTkButton(root, text = "File Upload",hover_color=("green"), command=schedule_import)
file_button.grid(row=5,column=0, padx=50, pady=150)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a file open exception and adjusted the padding of the button. so...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import customtkinter as ctk
import pandas as pd

def import_file_data():
    v = tk.StringVar()
    global file_data
    try:
        csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
        v.set(csv_file_path)
        file_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, encoding='unicode_escape')
        file_button.configure(fg_color = "green", hover_color="green")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = ctk.CTk()
    file_button = ctk.CTkButton(root, text = "File Upload", command=import_file_data)
    file_button.grid(row=5,column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    root.mainloop()
```